# Nuxt3 App problem with cloudinary uploadWidget

Tags: cloudinary, nuxt3

```html
<div class="img__container">
  <CldUploadWidget
    v-if="!editMiner.img"
    v-slot="{ open, widget }"
    uploadPreset="****"
    @upload="handleUploadClick($event.value.info)">
    <div
      @click="open"
      class="add__image d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
      <IconCSS size="65px" name="material-symbols:note-stack-add-outline" />
    </div>
  </CldUploadWidget>
  <div class="add__image" v-else>
    <CldUploadWidget
      v-slot="{ open, widget }"
      uploadPreset="****"
      @upload="handleUploadClick($event.value.info)">
      <div>
        <CldImage
          alt="miner-img"
          @click="open"
          width="150"
          height="150"
          :src="miner?.img || editMiner.img">
        </CldImage>
      </div>
    </CldUploadWidget>
  </div>
</div>
```

that opens uploadModal but only if i refresh the page, otherwise:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'open')`
`at invokeInstanceMethod (CldUploadWidget.vue:160:31)`
`at open (CldUploadWidget.vue:192:7)`
`at callWithErrorHandling (chunk-RAKT47ZN.js?v=f55911a4:1565:18)`
`at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (chunk-RAKT47ZN.js?v=f55911a4:1573:17)`
`at HTMLImageElement.invoker (chunk-RAKT47ZN.js?v=f55911a4:9397:5)`

i was trying to conditional render it but properties from v-slot are not reactive...

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're encountering issues with the reactivity of the v-slot properties in your conditional rendering. One approach to solve this issue is to use a computed property to conditionally render the upload widget. This way, you ensure that the component is only rendered when the necessary properties are available. I've not tested this out myself, so please tweak it as required, but this should be a good starting point:

```
<template>
  <div class="img__container">
    <template v-if="shouldRenderUploadWidget">
      <CldUploadWidget
        v-slot="{ open, widget }"
        uploadPreset="****"
        @upload="handleUploadClick($event.value.info)"
      >
        <div
          @click="open"
          class="add__image d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
        >
          <IconCSS
            size="65px"
            name="material-symbols:note-stack-add-outline"
          />
        </div>
      </CldUploadWidget>
    </template>
    <template v-else>
      <div class="add__image">
        <CldUploadWidget
          v-slot="{ open, widget }"
          uploadPreset="****"
          @upload="handleUploadClick($event.value.info)"
        >
          <div>
            <CldImage
              alt="miner-img"
              @click="open"
              width="150"
              height="150"
              :src="miner?.img || editMiner.img"
            ></CldImage>
          </div>
        </CldUploadWidget>
      </div>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    shouldRenderUploadWidget() {
      // Check if the necessary properties are available
      return (
        (!this.editMiner.img && this.$slots.default) || this.miner?.img
      );
    },
  },
  methods: {
    handleUploadClick(info) {
      // Handle the upload click event
      console.log('Uploaded info:', info);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: import { useSlots } from 'vue';
    const slots = useSlots();
    const shouldRenderUploadWidget = computed(() => {
      console.log(slots.default)
      return slots.default
    })

slots.default always return undefined. 
Im trying to render it if open in v-slot is initialized, but i dont know how to achieve this.